# Convert Byte Array to string using TransactSQL

Tags: c#, sql-server, t-sql, arrays

We are store string values in a database using varBinary type using c# and BinaryFormatter.We convert to byte array and then we save to DataBase

```
public static byte[] ToBytes(stringvalue)
{
  if (value == null)
    return null;

  byte[] inMemoryBytes;
  using (MemoryStream inMemoryData = new MemoryStream())
  {
    new BinaryFormatter().Serialize(inMemoryData, value);
    inMemoryBytes = inMemoryData.ToArray();
  }

  return inMemoryBytes;
}
```

OK, So if we save char "a", we can see "0x0001000000FFFFFFFF0100000000000000060100000001610B" in the database.After we can retrieve the data and convert again to string.
Can we convert this binary value ("0x0001000000FFFFFFFF0100000000000000060100000001610B") to char ("a") only using transact SQL (so we can do modifications, inserts, comparations from sql server console)?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 4):

You could to use something simpler, as

```
Encoding.Default.GetBytes("a");
```

That will return "61" and can be more easily translated to a varchar, just running this:

```
create table #sample (content varbinary(max));
insert into  #sample values (0x61)
select cast(content as varchar) from #sample
```

Comment: Thanks Rubens, but this tecnique is used for another framework (Entlib Contrib http://entlibcontrib.codeplex.com/) and cant change it.
They use it because then thay can store more types:ints,string,images etc etc and we want (only when the type is string) convert this stored values to string

Comment: Oscar, can `BitConverter.GetBytes` be useful?

Comment: but this is a method from the .Net framework,isnt it? I want to use only SqlConsole.
I´m programming it using CLR Sql functions, according Kleinux.
Thanks again.

Answer (score 2):

I'd suggest using the method described http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163473.aspx to use the .NET regex library.  Specifically the section for CLR User Defined Functions.  You could simply use the BinaryFormatter to deserialize your byte array.

```
[SqlFunction]
public static string ToStringFromBytes(byte[] value) 
{ if (value == null) return null;

  using (MemoryStream inMemoryData = new MemoryStream(value))
  {
    return new BinaryFormatter().Deserialize(inMemoryData) as string;
  }
}
```

Comment: You are rigth, I didnt remember about it... I going to see.
Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

Why can't you just store the original string in a `nvarchar(MAX)` type column?
If you have to use the `varbinary` type column, then at least use the `System.Text.Encoding` classes to do the conversion - then you can decode the strings in sql as well:

```
public static byte[] ToBytes(string value)
{
  if (value == null) return null;
  return System.Text.Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(value);
}
```

And then use it like this:

```
select cast(VarBinaryField as nvarchar(max)) from SomeTable
```

Comment: Thanks Pent, but this tecnique is used for another framework (Entlib Contrib http://entlibcontrib.codeplex.com/) and cant change it.
They use it because then thay can store more types:ints,string,images etc etc and we want (only when the type is string) convert this stored values to string

Comment: Then you could use CLR user defined functions as suggested by Kleinux.